AWS cloudfront giving the access denied error while trying to access S3 static web hosting image
S3 Policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1721361019639",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1721361016069",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dhruv-react-app-2/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2JOM2URUBUIP0"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dhruv-react-app-2/*"
        }
    ]
}

AWS cloudfront general page
https://i.sstatic.net/trvVE2zy.png
error
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>AM9NBX5C17WYBJ8G</RequestId>
<HostId>aQZcvuNwk/9BTlkR1B8s1Nx4uyo0gie0a7hu/He3Zwnk64SfhGVhbedSQBkPeyO/JXxuIjzBqps=</HostId>
</Error>

Website is  simply a react frontend react application.
I haven't changed the policy myself, it is done by cloudfront only, also i am able to access the static website directly through S3 but through cloudfront it is giving the above mentioned error
I am very new to using AWS so requesting community if i should be sharing more information let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Your website works fine when I go to a specific file (https://d2hb8qbel41p7k.cloudfront.net/index.html). This suggests that CloudFront is pointing at the bucket endpoint instead of the static website endpoint. Is your origin configured to point to https://dhruv-react-app-2.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ (S3 endpoint) or https://dhruv-react-app-2.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ (static website endpoint)? See: Website endpoints - Amazon Simple Storage Service

Side-note: Your bucket policy is making the entire bucket public. Therefore, you don't actually need the Origin Access Identity section. That is only required if you wish to keep the bucket private but still allow CloudFront to access the bucket.
